# Jquery $.get() RangeError Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was checking the Error Console in Safari while debugging a different issue (that issue is fixed now), and I noticed that it displayed the message "RangeError Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded". By commenting out code, I was able to pinpoint what was causing the issue. However, from searching around, I haven't found anyone else who had Jquery $.get() causing the issue. I'm not that familiar with ajax, but from eyeing the code I don't see any recursion that could cause this issue. Furthermore, if I comment out the code in the success function, I still get the error. But if I comment out the $.get call the error message goes away. The app works fine and never displays any alert error messages, but I'm just worried that this could become a bigger issue.

```
function update_database(newLat, newLng) {
    if (navigator.onLine && connectStatus) {
        $.get(GREEN_CAB_URL + "updatedatabase/", {
            lat: newLat,
            lng: newLng
        }, function(data) {
            data = data.substring(0, data.length - 1);
            data = "{\"recs\":[" + data + "]}";
            var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
            var arrr = arr.recs;
            if (clientdb) {
                clientdb.transaction(function(tx) {
                    for (var i in arrr) {
                        tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ads (ad_id, sec_filename, filename, lng, lat, radius, first_img_url, second_img_url, days, was_removed, business, phone_number, start_time_everyday, end_time_everyday, is_vid) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ", [arrr[i].id, arrr[i].second_filename, arrr[i].filename, arrr[i].lng, arrr[i].lat, arrr[i].radius, '<img src="' + GREEN_CAB_URL + arrr[i].filename + '" class="ads" />', '<img src="' + GREEN_CAB_URL + arrr[i].second_filename + '" class="secondad"/>', arrr[i].days, arrr[i].was_removed, arrr[i].business, arrr[i].phone_number, arrr[i].start_time_everyday, arrr[i].end_time_everyday, arrr[i].is_movie], insert_query_success, insert_error);
                    } // end of for(var i in arrr)
                }, function(err) {
                    alert("client.transaction error: " + err.message + "(code: " + err.code + ")")
                }, update_database_success);
            }
        }).error("updatedatabase ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a chainable error function that accepts a string ?

Comment: I did not. I inherited this project and was never sure what the .error("updatedatabase ERROR"); was referencing. After taking that out, I no longer get the error in the console. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!